# How would I use inline HTML elements in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

I am wondering if there were a way to use inline HTML like `<sup>` and `<sub>` elements in SVG?

For example:

```
<svg>
  <text x="0" y="12">Some text with a superscript <sup>1</sup> and a subscript <sub>2</sub>.</text>
</svg>
```

I can not find anything about using inline HTML elements in SVG. I am hoping to use superscript without having to use a styled `<tspan>`.

Comment: You have it right at the end i.e. use a styled tspan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem is using tspan elements and the attribute `baseline-shift` like so:

```css
tspan[baseline-shift]{font-size:50%;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 350 40">
  <text x="0" y="12">Some text with a superscript <tspan baseline-shift="super">1</tspan> and a subscript <tspan baseline-shift="sub">2</tspan>.</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that I would end up having to use ```<tspan>``` tags.

Answer (score 1):

> I can not find anything about using inline HTML elements in SVG. I am
>   hoping to use superscript without having to use a styled `<tspan>`.

You can use for these purposes: [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="450" height="100">
 <style type='text/css'>
    svg { border: 1px solid black; }
    svg div {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    padding:1em;
    }
  </style>
<foreignObject class="node" x="16" y="22" width="400" height="100">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>Some text with a superscript <sup>1</sup> and a subscript <sub>2</sub></div>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

*Example for wrapping multi-line text in svg just like in HTML*

```css
svg {
border: 1px solid black;
}
svg div{
border: 1px dotted blue;
padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="500">

<foreignObject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="200" height="500">
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. </div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can't do it that way cause you now have two body elements.

Comment: @Rob Of course, it could be made simpler as in the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). Inside the SVG there is HTML. But the SVG is an ordinary block element, which in turn can be added to the HTML

Comment: You are assuming that I am using SVG inside HTML. I am not. I am writing independent SVG images. Also, that appears to be overkill for _inline_ HTML elements. I was just talking about the text within a ```<text>``` element.

Comment: @Lady Aleena You wrote that you didn’t want to use tspan. Therefore, I was looking for another solution. The answer finalized. I didn’t know how you use SVG in the future. You didn’t write it anywhere Why put a minus right away?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things to get the superscript, and it is not supported the same across browsers.

For Firefox...

```css
tspan.sup { font-size: 50%; dominant-baseline: hanging; }
```

For Chrome (and Inkscape)...

```css
tspan.sup { font-size: 50%; baseline-shift: super; }
```

When both styles are used, Chrome will apply the `baseline-shift`, but it will not be entirely superscript. Inkscape will apply the `baseline-shift` correctly even with `dominant-baseline` present. It may be a case of choosing the browser you want to support.

And a non-CSS method.

```xml
<text x="0" y="14">Some text<tspan dy ="-10">1</tspan></text>

# If there is more text is after the tspan, do the following.

<text x="0" y="14">Some text<tspan dy ="-10">e</tspan> <tspan dy="10">with more text.</tspan></text>
```